# different exceptions for each controller cakephp

Tags: php, cakephp

I want to create exceptions for each controller in my project with cakephp. Example:

```
class UsersController extends AppController {

    public function add(){

        if(!$this->User->save($this->request->data)){
            throw new UserException('Error save User/add'); 
        }

    }

}

class FriendsController extends AppController {

    public function add(){

        if(!$this->Friend->save($this->request->data)){
            throw new FriendException('Error save Friend/add');
        }

    }

}
```

I'm trying this, but does not work...never paint the log in class exception user/friend

In app/Config/core.php

```
Configure::write('Exception.handler', 'UserException::handle');
Configure::write('Exception.handler', 'FriendException::handle');
```

In app/Config/bootstrap.php

```
App::uses('UserException', 'Lib');
App::uses('FriendException', 'Lib');
```

In app/Lib/UserException.php

```
class UserException {
    public static function handle($error) {
        $this->log($error)
    }
}
```

In app/Lib/FriendException.php

```
class FriendException {
    public static function handle($error) {
        $this->log($error)
    }
}
```

Any idea?
Regards!

Comment: Why don't you use a `try catch`.?

Comment: In each function?I did it. But i want to send and email when an error occurs. In log Always:  Fatal Error (1): Class 'UserException' not found in

Answer (score 0):

An exception for each controller seems quite redundant. Why do you need 2 exception classes `UserException` and `FriendException` when they are identical, only difference being the message you pass? Also logging feature is inbuilt in core's `ExceptionHandler`. You can just throw a `CakeException` or `RuntimeException` with required message.

Do you realize your code:

```
Configure::write('Exception.handler', 'UserException::handle');
Configure::write('Exception.handler', 'FriendException::handle');
```

is overwriting the config same variable?

Anyway the `'Exception.handler'` config is meant to specify the class with handles ALL your exceptions. You can confusing an exception class with an error handler class. Exception classes don't have any `handle()` method. Your exception classes should extend `CakeException` and override required method/property.

Comment: Now i only have a exception. In my controller i put: throw new AppExceptionHandler('Exception error'); but the log says: Class 'AppExceptionHandler' not found

Comment: You are still not understanding the difference between an exception and exception handler. Your are supposed to throw an exception class instance not exception handler class instance.

Answer (score 0):

Use the [CakeDC Utils plugin](https://github.com/CakeDC/utils), it comes with an [EmailErrorHandler](https://github.com/CakeDC/utils/blob/master/Error/EmailErrorHandler.php) that is configurable and can send an email depending on the error level.